# What's the clearest way to code a Ruby method with an if/then/else condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have this class-level method in an ActiveRecord model class.

```
def self.is_animal_color_correct?(animal, color)
  if AnimalColor.find_by_animal_and_color(animal.downcase, color.downcase) 
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

I'm just wondering what the best way to format the method is. This seems verbose, but very clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this particular example, I think this is what you want instead:

```
AnimalColor.exists?(:animal => animal.downcase, :color => color.downcase)
```

In general, you should not care as long as you are checking against truthy, that anything not null or false.

Answer (score 4):

```
def self.is_animal_color_correct?(animal, color)
  AnimalColor.find_by_animal_and_color(animal.downcase, color.downcase) 
end
```

It is idiomatic in Ruby to use `nil` and `false` as non-truthy values and real values (when available) for truthy ones. With your `if/else` you are actively discarding information that might be useful somewhere else, and doing more work in the process.

If you really really really want your method to return only `true` or `false`, you could:

```
def self.is_animal_color_correct?(animal, color)
  !!AnimalColor.find_by_animal_and_color(animal.downcase, color.downcase) 
end
```

But again, this is not idiomatic Ruby, and I do not recommend it.

Comment: I understand this, but the return value isn't a boolean (not that that really matters I guess). I guess this is part of my question -- should I return an object when I what I want is a boolean result. I'm trying to think if there are any situations where that could cause a problem.

Comment: in Ruby, nil and false are the two only values which don't pass an if condition. So it's just fine

Comment: @Kevin: if you want a boolean, put `!!` in front of the find, which is also quite idiomatic.

Comment: IIRC, a lot of boolean ruby methods actually return objects, not true or false.  For example `foo && bar`  will actually return the value of `bar` if both were truthy.

Comment: @DGM. Yes, but that's short-circuiting. If a method is called *something?* it's definitely expected to return a boolean. By the way, just create a Object#to_bool method in your extensions library, and avoid writing !! which looks ugly.